ConTeXt: How do I achieve an expection to the styling in an \environment?
DISCLAIMER: I'm newbie to ConTeXt. I started learning yesterday by spending a 3 hour train ride reading the Not So Short Introduction by Joaquín Ataz-López. I am also not a student or doing this in an academic environment nor am I in the typesetting industry. I simply wrote a research paper that I think deserves better typesetting than is possible with Atlassian Confluence. Thus, I don't have colleagues to ask about this kind of thing. They already think I'm an overachiever because I wrote a research paper that nobody asked for.
I am confused about how to achieve two things simultaneously:

I would like big spacing between paragraphs
I would like small spacing between enumerated items

Chatgpt suggests:
\setupwhitespace[big]
\starttext
... my paragraphs
\stoptext
\setupwhitespace[none]
\starttext
... my enumerated items
\stoptext

However, I've structured my project with multiple files as shown below. In my preamble I have used \setupwhitespace[big]. I've looked at the documentation for \startitemize and \setupitemgroup. There doesn't seem to be an option for spacing between items.
\environment preamble.tex

\starttext
    \ReadFile{file1.tex}
    \ReadFile{file2.tex}
\stoptext

I really just want to change the spacing for the enumerated items but keep all the rest of the styling in the preamble.
My questions are:

Is it an antipattern to wrap all of these files in a single \starttext ... \stoptext?
If I set all of my styling in an \environment, how do I achieve an exception to that styling in a short block of text?


Welcome to TeX.SE! One usually goes with one \starttext and \stoptext and the content of the document inbetween. Good luck with the typesetting (I just saw below that you found some solution)!

Ok as I was doing a final review of this question I realized that the URL of the Ataz-López's book had "githubusercontent" in the path. I took a look at the source code.
In the frontmatter he has:
\startitemize[packed]
...

This achieves what I would like it to achieve for this example.
